# How to sort linked list

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I am trying to sort a linear linked list by last name, however it is crashing, also i don't know if my algorithm is working correctly.

Can someone help me to stop it from crashing, and see if my algorithm for sorting the list is working?

```
void sort(NODEPTR *employees, int maxEmployees)
{
  int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
  NODEPTR p, q, pTrail = NULL, qTrail, temp;
  temp = (NODEPTR) calloc(1, sizeof(node));

  qTrail = *employees;
  q = (*employees)->next;
  for (i = 0; i < maxEmployees; i++)
  {

    p = *employees;

    while (p != q)
    {

      if (strcmp(p->lastName, q->lastName))
      {
        temp = q;
        qTrail = q->next;
        q = pTrail->next;

        temp = pTrail->next;
        pTrail = temp;

        p = q;
      }
      else
      {
        pTrail = p;
        p = p->next;
      }

    }
    qTrail = q;
    q = q->next;

    pTrail = NULL;
  }
  printf("%10s %10ss\n", "First", "Last");
  printf("%10s %10s\n", "-----", "----");

  for (i = 0; i < maxEmployees; i++)
  {
    printf("%10s %10ss\n", (*employees)->firstName, (*employees)->lastName);
  }
}
```

Linked List:

```
typedef struct node
{
  char firstName[11];
  char lastName[16];
  char gender;
  int tenure;
  char rate;
  float salary;
  struct node *next;
} node, *NODEPTR;
```

Comment: Instead of switching the whole nodes with places you should switch just their content and leave the bindings untouched. Also would be nice to know what is your crash error.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie But if the nodes are large, that would turn the program incredibly slow...

Comment: @Lundin well basicly yes, but in his case it is not that big. Furthermore it lacks the OP from committing any memory leaks.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie: I feel switching the nodes is *much more elegant* as it make the *algorithm independend of the nodes' payload**.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic seems to be wrong:

`strcmp()` will return **three** values.

- `1` if first argument's value is >
- `-1` if second argument's value is >
- `0` if both arguments's value are same.

So based on `strcmp(p->lastName,q->lastName)` you can not sort.

You should change the position only when `strcmp()` return `1`. for `-1` and `0` it should go in `else` part.

Comment: No, never, ever, make the (rather invalid) assumption that `strcmp` returns only the values `-1`, `0` or `1`. It is perfectly standards-conforming for `strcmp("a", "c")` to return `-2`.

Comment: More importantly, it is perfectly standards-conforming for `strcmp("a","c")` to return `-97` (or `-9000`). The _only_ guarantees you have about the return value are that it is an `int`, that it will be zero if the two strings are identical, that it will be nonzero if the two strings differ in any regard, and that... "The sign of a non-zero return value shall be determined by the sign of the difference between the values of the first pair of bytes (both interpreted as type unsigned char) that differ in the strings being compared.".